# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' on virtual environment

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

Pip doesn't work in my virtual environment. As I create a virtual env, it works fine for the first time, and it doesn't seem to work the next time. Even after I upgrade pip to the latest version, it throws the same error. How may I solve this issue?

> pip freeze
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "D:\Fast\name\venv\Scripts\pip.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'pip'**

Comment: have you tried `pip3`?

Comment: What is your Python setup? What OS are you using? What commands did you do to set up your virtual environment? Can you run `python -m pip`?

Comment: @anurag I tried pip3, still it says "No Module named pip"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, follow these steps:
(*Works for Python 3.6 and above*)

1. Download this file: **https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py**
2. Open **cmd**, go to the path where the file is downloaded and run the following command:

   ```sh
   python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
   ```

Verify if `pip` is re-installed:

```sh
pip3 -V
```

[*These generic steps should work on any OS!*]

Comment: same on linux btw